# How much an iterator should do

Tags: strings, graph, loops, iterator

I am working on creating iterators, for strings, lists, trees, graphs, and potentially other things.

First a side note.

---

I have a string data type in my engine. The string is implemented as a bunch of small chunks separated physically in memory, let's say 256-byte chunks. So a single string might look like this in memory.

```
asdfasdfasd...256
[something else]
[something else]
fasdfasdfasdf
```

So the final string would be:

```
asdfasdfasd...256fasdfasdfasdf
```

However, when in code, I want to access the string like this:

```
string[10]

for (char in string) {
  // ...
}
```

Basically, it *feels* like a simple array.

But when you access a character in string, it has to have some context. It needs to know which chunk we are currently on, the length of chunks, and if another chunk follows this current chunk. There's a lot under the hood of `for (char in string)`.

---

Given that, I was thinking of having an iterator implement this. But the first part of my confusion is how much should go into the iterator, vs. how much should go into some generic looper/api that takes the iterator as an argument.

For example.

```
iterator.iterate(function(item, index){

})
```

The iterator does everything. This would mean, if we were implementing "graph traversal", there would be an entire graph traversal algorithm in the iterator, and it would take a graph as input. This would mean that we could have multiple different iterators like a DFS and a BFS iterator, etc.

But we could instead have it split between the iterator and the outside syntax:

```
for (item, index in iterator.next()) {
  // ...
}
```

This seems like what you see more often, but it seems to make implementation harder as the state is now split between the external environment and the iterator. Maybe not though.

The reason for asking is because there are these cases:

- while loop
- for loop
- get item at index like `string[10]`
- get item by name (hashtable)
- etc.

It seems that if you want to have a generic API to iterating these things, or accessing these properties, you need an abstraction layer like the iterator on top of it. Wondering if that is true, or if not, what options there are.

Comment: It would be inappropriate to use the name `iterator` for a graph search/traversal task, iterators are understood to provide 1-dimensional travel. An `iterator` on a graph would be expected to return all nodes in no particular order.

Comment: @whatsisname I don't know if this is a coding horror or not, but I've seen code that iterated a three dimensional point through all the points from the starting point, progressing outward in a slowly expanding cube, until it would start the cube at the specified target radius, and it seemed easy enough to work with.

Comment: You may want to search for articles describing the pros and cons of "internal iteration" vs "external iteration".

Comment: Do you have any experience with LINQ and `IEnumerable` from the .NET world? They provide a very reasonable iterator model, you may consider to learn from it.

Comment: @EdGrimm that's one dimension of iteration. It just maps to a path in 3d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different iterators provide different contracts. C++ probably has the most fine-grained iterator concepts, distinguishing operators that

- can move forward
- can move backwards
- can jump to another element by random access
- can read elements
- can write the accessed element

Similarly, Java iterators only move in one direction but can optionally delete the current element from the containing collection.

The most general kind of iterator is an iterator that only moves forward to the next element and only provides read access to that element. This can be implemented via an object with a `next()` method that both moves forward and returns the next value.

There are different approaches to detect the end of the iterator. There could be an explicit method to check whether the end has been reached, but that makes the implementation of the iterator more complicated (possibly, the end cannot be detected without creating the next element, which could be costly for lazy streams). Instead, the `next()` method will typically return a sentinel value such as `None` or throw an exception.

This next()-based iterator is very primitive, but allows you to implement all kinds of semantics on top of it. Compare also how you can implement any for-loop in terms of a while-loop. In particular, an item–index iterator could be implemented either

- by having the collection implement an iterator that directly yields an item–index tuple, or
- by creating an iterator decorator that counts the past items, like `enumerate()` in Python.

Some kind of functionality is simply out of scope for an iterator, such as offering indexed access to some collection. An iterator may be a cursor into a collection, but may also not be related to any collection. Instead, iterators are sometimes used for data streams, lazy computations, or simple kinds of reactive programming. Iterators are also closely related to coroutines and can therefore be used to implement interesting control flow abstractions.

If the language already has some context of iterators, you should definitively use that protocol/interface. Do not invent your own iterator system that competes with them. In particular, do not create a callback-based iteration protocol when the language already has an object-based iterator approach.

However, some data structures benefit from letting the user decide how to traverse the data structure.

- Graphs may want to offer iterators for common iteration orders (e.g. iterating a tree in-order or depth-first), but will generally want to offer the user full control as to how to traverse the graph. This could mean that you offer no iteration abstraction at all, but just expose a list of reachable nodes.
- If an object graph consists of objects of different types, a callback based approach such as the Visitor Pattern could be more appropriate.

Comment: In my case I am considering how `for (var key in object)` in JS is implemented. I think it is a hash table underneath, so it does all kinds of stuff in the `for (var key`, it looks up in the hash table. So I wonder if this sort of thing is an iterator or something else.

Comment: @LancePollard The ECMAScript standard defines for-in loops in terms of an iterator object (https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enumerate-object-properties), although a real-world implementation would likely use some kind of external iteration where the iteration code is part of the loop. You're right though that JS objects behave like hash tables, but this doesn't mean it physically is a hash table.